# A word for the machine that tells a news reader what to say (using scrolling subtitles)

Tags: meaning, word-request

A news reader (*news anchor* in the U.S.) looks into a camera.  The camera has a screen that faces the news reader.  Scrolling lines appear on the screen, and the news reader reads them.

What is it called? Is there a single word term for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but check [***teleprompter***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprompter).

Answer (score 1):

In British English, we call that the *autocue*.

> [**autocue**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/autocue):
>
> A device which projects an enlarged image of a script on to a clear glass screen in front of a person speaking on television or in public, so enabling the speaker to read their speech while appearing to be looking at the viewers or audience.

Answer (score -1):

Am not sure of single word, but one of the common term for the device, which I believe can also be used for the words is: `electronic speech notes`